# Why is my program not printing data from the table I am scraping?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-table, cryptocurrency, inspect

I am currently struggling to create a program that scrapes data from the table on https://coinmarketcap.com. I see that I am in a bit over my head. However, I am trying to learn how it all works to be able to do it on my own. So far, my program prints a cryptocurrencies rank, name, and ticker symbol. Now, I am working to scrape the dynamically changing price from the table. Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://coinmarketcap.com"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
rank = 1

for td in soup.select("td:nth-of-type(3)"):
    t = " ".join(tag.text for tag in td.select("p, span")).strip()
    print(rank, "|", end =" "); print("{:<30} {:<10}".format(*t.rsplit(maxsplit=1)))
    rank = rank + 1

    for td in soup.select("td:nth-of-type(4)"):
        t = " ".join(tag.text for tag in td.select("a")).strip()

    print("{}_1d".format(t.rsplit(maxsplit=1)))
```

this prints as follows:

```
1 | Bitcoin                        BTC
[]_1d
2 | Ethereum                       ETH
[]_1d
3 | Tether                         USDT
[]_1d
4 | Binance Coin                   BNB
[]_1d


and so on...
```

How can I have it print the current price of the crypto and not just literal text? I can figure out the formatting on my own, just need help displaying the actual data. Any help is greatly appreciated. And if you can explain your solution, that would be even more helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following issues in your code:

- Your line `print("{}_1d".format(t.rsplit(maxsplit=1)))`, is outside the inner for loop, this makes only the last value of `t` to be printed (which is empty).
  So, correcting this to put it inside the loop along with a change to not print every `t` value is what is required.
- You have put the price loop (td:nth-of-type(4)) inside the td:nth-of-type(3) loop. This makes the entire price loop run repeatedly everytime the outer loop runs once
- If you print the value of td in the loop with (td:nth-of-type(4)), you will find that the  tag is not present in your response after the first ~10 results. Using td.text will get you the required result.

I have slightly modified your code to fix some of the issues:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://coinmarketcap.com"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
rank = 1

t1, t2 = [], []

for td in soup.select("td:nth-of-type(3)"):
    t1.append(" ".join(tag.text for tag in td.select("p, span")).strip())

for td in soup.select("td:nth-of-type(4)"):
    t2.append(td.text)

for i in range(0, len(t1)):
    rank = rank + 1
    print(rank, "|", end =" "); print("{:<30} {:<10}".format(*t1[i].rsplit(maxsplit=1)))
    print("{}_1d".format(t2[i]))
```

Comment: I appreciate the help. I tried this same strategy with the next column (24 hour percentages). However, it only outputs the first 10 values even while using td.text, am I missing something?

Comment: From the code you have written in the question, it looks to be that you were trying to get the values using the anchor tag. And since, the anchor tags are only present for the first 10 values, you were not able to output more than that. I think when you used `td.text`, you might have done something similar which gave you the anchor tags and hence only the first 10 values.

Answer (score 0):

To get price of crypto-currencies you can use next example:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://coinmarketcap.com"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

for rank, td in enumerate(soup.select("td:nth-of-type(3)"), 1):
    t = " ".join(tag.text for tag in td.select("p, span")).strip()
    price = td.find_next("td").text
    print(
        "{:<3} | {:<30} {:<10} {:<10}".format(
            rank, *t.rsplit(maxsplit=1), price
        )
    )
```

Prints:

```
1   | Bitcoin                        BTC        $39,971.37
2   | Ethereum                       ETH        $2,320.27 
3   | Tether                         USDT       $1.00     
4   | Binance Coin                   BNB        $314.10   
5   | Cardano                        ADA        $1.28     
6   | XRP                            XRP        $0.7078   
7   | USD Coin                       USDC       $1.00     
8   | Dogecoin                       DOGE       $0.2043   
9   | Polkadot                       DOT        $15.11    
10  | Binance USD                    BUSD       $1.00     
11  | Uniswap                        UNI        $19.24    
12  | Bitcoin Cash                   BCH        $517.07   
13  | Litecoin                       LTC        $140.07   
14  | Chainlink                      LINK       $19.02    
15  | Solana                         SOL        $29.55    
16  | Wrapped Bitcoin                WBTC       $39923.81 
17  | Polygon                        MATIC      $1.02     
18  | Stellar                        XLM        $0.27     
19  | Ethereum Classic               ETC        $48.75    
20  | THETA                          THETA      $5.99     

...and so on.
```